# mongoose findOneAndUpdate gives different user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to $pull an object inside my cart collections. but after I make a request and sent a specific _id it gives me a different person.

this was the _id I sent from my client side.

```
{ id: '62a849957410ef5849491b1b' } /// from console.log(req.params);
```

here's my mongoose query.

```
export const deleteItem = (req,res) => {

    const { id } = req.params;

    console.log(id);

    try {

        if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'ID not found' });
        
        ClientModels.findOneAndUpdate(id, {
            $pull: {
                cart: {
                    product_identifier: req.body.cart[0].product_identifier
                }
            }
        },{
            new: true
        }).then(val => console.log(val)).catch(temp => console.log(temp));

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json(error);
    }
}
```

after the request here's the callback.

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62a77ab16210bf1afd8bd0a9"),
  fullname: 'Gino Dela Vega',
  address: '008 Estrella.st santo cristo',
  email: 'gamexgaming1997@gmail.com',
  google_id: 'none',
  birthday: '1997-12-30',
  number: 9922325221,
  gender: 'Male',
  username: 'ginopogi',
  password: '$2b$12$YCc1jclth.ux4diwpt7EXeqYyLOG0bEaF.wvl9hkqNVptY.1Jsuvi',
  cart: [],
  wishlist: [],
  toBeDeliver: [],
  Delivered: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

as you guys can see after sending a specific _id to find a user...the callback gives me a different user reason that I can't pull the specific object inside cart. (the object I was trying to pull is on another user)

Comment: _"`id || req.params`"_ 

Comment: I tried id and req.params already and both are working the same ...since after the request it gives a different user

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `findOneAndUpdate` expect a filter as first parameter, try to switch to `findByIdAndUpdate` if you want to filter by a specific `_id`:

```
export const deleteItem = (req, res) => {
    ...

    ClientModels.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      {
        $pull: {
          cart: {
            product_identifier: req.body.cart[0].product_identifier,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        new: true,
      }
    )
      .then((val) => console.log(val))
      .catch((temp) => console.log(temp));
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json(error);
  }
};
```